# How to get all models of a table with one hasMany relationship to json in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, model

**Goal**
Get all models with a certain hasMany relationship data in json format. I think, you could also say: A collection with the hasMany relationship data in json.
I have two tables: `template` and `template_field` and two models.

**First Model**

```
class Template extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @return HasMany 
     */
    public function templateField(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TemplateField::class);
    }
}
```

**Second Model**

```
class TemplateField extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo 
     */
    public function template(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Template::class);
    }
}
```

What i can do is: `Template::all()->toJson()`. But then templateField data is missing.

**Edit**
This works.

```
$collection = Template::with('templateField')->get();
$collection->toJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Template::with('templateField')->get();

return response()->json([
  'status' => true,
  'data'   => $collection
], 200);
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, but that isn't what im looking for. I want the data of the hasMany relationship inside the json.

Comment: You should add some explanation to your code so that the OP can understand it better.